# Extracting Topic and Subtopic Name from.JPG Image

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, ocr, python-tesseract

[I am trying to extract the subtopics from .jpg .pytesscrect reads the whole text of the  image where as i require subtopic names liquid form ,gaseous form,water vapour.I used layout-parser model on these images but it failed very badly. Please help me   ]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abLgn.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.